# Stripping source code of unneccessary functions

Tags: c#, structure

Let's say I have a complicated program created by someone else as Source because it is OpenSource. I need only a small part of it, but it seems to be interconnected.

How do I automatically strip the program off everything I don't need in Visual c#?

For instance, I define two values I want to keep, ie two variables already existing in the original code and an addon(?) should *remove* everything that does *not* influence these two values, including gui-elements.

How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your reply.

Comment: Such thing does not exist, in that I'm pretty sure. You'll have to refactor the project and split the one big program to parts, each on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a software solution to a problem that requires human reasoning. This is your job. Using find/replace and a tool such as ReSharper can make your job easier.

Comment: How does ReSharper help achieving this goal he has?

Comment: ReSharper is great for re-factoring code. The OP could use it to find usages of the two variables in question and begin removing other code. ReSharper highlights unused methods and can delete methods and all usages of them. If I were to do what the OP has in mind, ReSharper would be a tool I'd like to have available.

Comment: Actually, that software solution is called "a linker".